# Every model of ZFC has an element that is a model of ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

Please see Joel Hamkins answer:  https://mathoverflow.net/q/51786.

A section from his argument:

> Suppose that M is a model of ZFC. Thus, in particular, ZFC is
>   consistent. If it happens that M is ω-standard, meaning that it has
>   only the standard natural numbers, then M has all the same proofs and
>   axioms in ZFC that we do in the meta-theory, and so M agrees that ZFC
>   is consistent. In this case, by the Completeness theorem applied in M,
>   it follows that there is a model m which M thinks satisfies ZFC, and
>   so it really does.

I don't understand the following two inferences:

1) "then M has all the same proofs and axioms in ZFC that we do in the meta-theory, *and so* M agrees that ZFC is consistent"

2) "it follows that there is a model m which M thinks satisfies ZFC, *and so* it really does"

Mainly, for (1) M agrees that ZFC is conistent because its an arithmetical statement and those are absolute for $\omega$-models, so what does this have to do with having "all the same proofs and axioms in ZFC that we do in the meta-theory". And for (2) why does $M \models (m \models \text{ZFC})$ imply $m \models \text{ZFC}$? After all, we didn't assume $M$ was transitive. I only know that the $\models$-relation is absolute for *transitive* models of $\text{ZF-P}$ (I think?).

Comment: For (2) I think that, since $M$ is $\omega$-standard, what $M$ believes to be $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and the "true" $\mathsf{ZFC}$ of the meta theory agree, so the structure $m$ that $M$ believes to satisfy $\mathsf{ZFC}$ actually satisfies the true $\mathsf{ZFC}$

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Why would the fact that M and the universe agree on what ZFC is imply that the universe agrees with M on what $\models$ means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is what do you mean by a "model of ZFC". If you mean the axioms as *we* enumerate them, in the meta-theory, this may or may not be the same thing as those of the universe of sets in which we are looking. The same can be told about the inference rules of FOL.

But since we can code everything into integers, that means that if we have a model whose integers are standard (read: agree with the meta-theory), then these problems go away.

What does that mean? Well, if the model was a model of ZFC, then it proves the completeness theorem, and since the arithmetic statement "ZFC is consistent" is true, that means that we can find a model of ZFC, and that it is the same ZFC as our meta-theory's one.

You might want to argue that the relation of that model might not be "correct" in some way, but we can make this model internally countable and the relation is then coded by a subset of $\omega$. So it's all good.

Comment: I'm not sure about your last sentence. Do you mean to say that inside M we can code $m \models \text{ZFC}$ as a statement about reals (subsets of $\omega$) because m can be assumed countable (from M)? But then 1) don't we need m to be hereditarily countable? 2)  are these statements absolute for $\omega$-models? I am not familiar with coding, except from what I know of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_(set_theory) .

Comment: Inside $M$ we can assume that the model is $\omega$ with some relation on $\omega$. Now, you since the definition of $\models$ is recursive (using the atomic diagram as a parameter), this relation is *really* modeling ZFC on $\omega$.

Comment: (Generally speaking, when you say "coding" in set theory you mean a bijection into some robust object, e.g. a set of ordinals. This means that all the pairs, tuples, etc, are all coded uniformly into a single set of ordinals.)

Comment: I've took some time of to digest, things are clearer now, but: from $M \models (m \models \text{ZFC}^M)$ and $\text{ZFC}^M = \text{ZFC}$, why does it follow that $m \models \text{ZFC}$? Because $M$ is not necessarily transitive, we cannot make use of the result that $\models$ is absolute for transitive models of ZF-P, correct?

Comment: If the two models agree on $\sf ZFC$, then they necessarily agree on $\omega$, so they agree on the definition of satisfaction.

Comment: Can you expand? I don't think I understand either of those two claims very well.

Comment: If $M$ and $V$ disagree on $\omega$, then $M$ has non-standard integers, and thus non-standard variable indices (think $x_n$ for non-standard $n$), and thus non-standard axioms in $\sf ZFC$. Since the two agree on the axioms, it means that they agree on $\omega$ as well. But now look at the definition of the satisfaction relation, it's a recursive definition on $\omega$, and on formulas. As $M$ and $V$ agree on all of these things, they agree on the satisfaction relation. Note that $(m,\in)$ might not be a model of $\sf ZFC$, but *there is some relation* $E$ such that $(m,E)\models\sf ZFC$.

Comment: I see. So the hidden argument goes something like: $M$ has a model $m$ that models actual ZFC. Then by downward LS we can assume $m$ is countable and hence without loss of generality that the model is $\omega$ with some relation on $\omega$. Then by inspection of the definition of $\models$, in this case, we find that it is arithmetical and therefore, since $M$ is an $\omega$-model, in $V$ we must also have that $m$ models actual ZFC.

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to clarify what's going on.

Comment: So this is a considerable strengthening (not requiring that $M$ is transitive) of the usual theorem that $\models$ is absolute for transitive models of ZF-P.

Comment: Is that a common theorem? Because it's not in Kunen e.g. and Hamkins glosses over it even though the rest of his argument is quite detailed.

Comment: That definitions by recursion are absolute if all the sets used in the recursion are the same between the models (including the index set, here $\omega$)? That is more or less an immediate observation one should make upon reflecting on the nature of $\models$.

Comment: I think what makes it difficult for beginners is that we cannot really fully flash out the definition of $\models$ as a formula. So yes, I'd expect someone to mention it, especially in a textbook. I didn't find it very easy either to see that $\models$ is absolute for transitive models of ZF-P, and to be quite frank, although I can convince myself for 99% that the proof I know works, the complexity of the formulas involved prevents me from being really really sure about it (like I would say for the infinitude of primes). Maybe you see more than I do?

Comment: Being on the topic: in the second part of that answer by Hamkins, were we assume that $M$ is _not_ $\omega$-standard, why does $M \models ((V_\alpha)^M \models \text{ZFC})$ imply $(V_\alpha)^M \models \text{ZFC}$, where ZFC refers to the actual ZFC?